# Announcing our new Stack Overflow Moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election

One of our beloved SO mods, [0x7fffffff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716216/0x7fffffff) is stepping down. As a result we had a hole to fill, and we've called up 2 runners-up from the previous election. Both [Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) and [TheLostMind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193767/thelostmind) have agreed to take 0x7fffffff's place and help out with the workload.

[image: Undo] [image: TheLostMind]

Please welcome them to the team!  And thank 0x7fffffff for his service to the community!

> **Moderator's Note**
>
> While 0x7fffffff, TheLostMind and Undo are very thankful and appreciative of your best wishes, we don't require a consistent stream of answers all saying thanks (they appreciate it though - they really do!).

Comment: Thank you for your service, 0x7fffffff - and all the best on your future journey towards Int64!

Comment: Congrats Undo and TheLostMind, Best of luck in your future endeavors, 0x7fffffff :-)

Comment: I step away for lunch and come back to two new mods! Congrats, Undo and TheLostMind, and thanks for your all your hard work, 0x7fffffff!

Comment: Cool, thanks @0x7fffffff. Congrats Undo and TheLostMind (What to do to the SO limitation of "only two at users can be notified?").

Comment: @KedarMhaswade None of them can be notified here. [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: @KedarMhaswade and everyone else: Thank you! I'll do my best not to disappoint.

Comment: Wow, while reading this Q and As, for a moment of time I've got a feeling that we're all one big family! Don't why I'm saying this. And I don't know theese three guys, but I'd like to speak from my heart and tell them "Thank you, men!". Your activity produces a lot of good so the show must go on. Strike sails! Give no quarter!!! *Marked as favorite.

Comment: Welcome Undo and TheLostMind! Thanks for your great service 0x7fffffff!

Comment: TheLostMind has decided to go with the name _TheWonMind_ after seeing this post.

Comment: Please, we only picked up Undo because he should have won in the first place. Let's not get too far ahead of ourselves.

Comment: @TheLostMind where ar you? Congrats.. First Indian to become a SO mod.

Comment: Congrats @Undo and TheLostMind, not forget to thanks to 0x7fffffff for the service

Comment: Congratzz TheLostMind and Undo.

Comment: TheLostMind and Undo should be the ones posting an answer here rather than you guys. Shouldn't we be congratulating them in _comments_ ?

Comment: welcom and we hope that you enjoy this work

Comment: In the community from a few days but enjoying it, thanks for your work!!!

Comment: Congratulations Guys ! Good Luck and thanks to 0x7fffffff for his service !

Comment: Thanks a lot. We appreciate your support @0x7fffffff and best of luck for your future endeavors. Congrats TheLostMind and Undo.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Thank you very much for service. Also, congratulation to Undo and TheLostMind

Comment: Much as I hate to be the party pooper but can we lock this (not-)question in its entirety? Now all proper welcomes, thankyous, and fare-thee-wells have been exchanged, it appears to me this has now become a low-rep user magnet to kiss up the "new management".

Comment: Congratzz TheLostMind and Undo

Comment: Woww..finally undo you are mod.. so happy.. all the best :)

Answer (score 317):

I'd like to start by congratulating both Undo and TheLostMind on their new positions. I know they'll be great!

I'd also like to thank the Stack Overflow community for having me, and allowing me to serve them. It's been my pleasure. Lately, I've been unable to contribute as much as you all deserve from a moderator, and I'd rather step down than give you a subpar moderation experience.

Thank you all very much, and best of luck to the new mods!!!

Comment: I hope you're sticking around as a regular user. Don't go changing your handle to `NSNotFound`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'll still be around :) Although, that would be great handle to use if I ever go missing!

Comment: Thanks for everything. And...watch out for signed integer overflow!

Comment: Feels good when they have to appoint not one but two new moderators just to replace you? ;)

Comment: Too bad you had to step down sir [0x7fffffff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/716216/0x7fffffff) . We Thank you for your service in Our community

Comment: A really big THANK YOU sir for your serving all of us. We are sad to see you away from moderation, but will be very happy to see you wandering around SO - so don't go missing if possible. :)

Answer (score 69):

I believe that *losing your mind* is exactly what you need to do in order to be voluntarily demoted to Stack Overflow janitor.

There are also a lot of posts that need to be *undone*.

Both candidates seem perfect for the job!

May Jon Skeet have mercy on your souls!

Comment: Hahahahahah that's some meta-meta-joke

Comment: Well said Carpetsmoker, well Said..

Comment: Exactly... _janitors_.

Comment: Luckily the big John Skeet in the sky's mercy is big and wide.

Answer (score 63):

Congratulations Undo and TheLostMind.  The both of you should do an excellent job.

Now get off of meta and get to work ;)

0x7fffffff Now that you are no longer a mod take a break and enjoy the meta high life.  Thank you for all the work you have done.

Answer (score 32):

Well, looks like all those flags on Hardware Recommendations are mine now, Undo... :P

Congratulations to both of you - I hope you enjoy the job, and I have no doubt you'll do us proud.

Thanks once again to 0x7fffffff for your service, and all the best in your future career. I hope to see you around.

Answer (score 14):

I often see Undo in [SO Close Vote Review room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). He is actively working for the betterment of this site. Hoping the best for Undo and also for TheLostMind. Congrats Guys! Cheers!

Comment: one up for neferpitou!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your service, *0x7fffffff*, and welcome  Undo and TheLostMind. It is great to see SO transferring reigns successfully from old to new mods. Any organization that can properly manage position changes is likely in for good fortune.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @0x7fffffff for your many years of devoted service!  This community works very well thanks to people like you.

I also want  to congratulate @Undo and @TheLostMind for their new assignment.

Comment: Totally agreed. Have a good life 0x7fffffff. To new mods: You are most welcome.