# Moderator Election 2016?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

The fall arrived, and I am wondering if something is planned for 2016?

Looking at the [election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) I notice a gap since the last election.

I am not candidate at all, and I am not asking for an election! Just curious :)

Comment: Ready the cannons!

Comment: Nope, not as such.

Comment: I don't know, "when we need to" seems like a pretty year-independent answer.

Comment: [When do moderator elections take place?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-do-moderator-elections-take-place)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the last [election was a year ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311045/november-2015-stack-overflow-community-moderator-election-results) and then in [March 2016, we brought up 2 additional moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318714/announcing-our-new-stack-overflow-moderators) to help out with the load.

At this time, we've got nothing scheduled...but we'll be revisiting it again soon.

Comment: The Purge will Continue Until All Parties are Feeling Patriotic.